# Creating a matrix from an array using numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I have a NumPy array `Y` with size `n` including integers.

```
Y = [1 1 2 0 ..... ]
```

Without using loops, is it possible to form a matrix `(k, n)` such that each column has 1 at the index position `Y[i]` and `0` elsewhere?

Comment: What is the definition of `k`?

Comment: Show us the loops attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `n` is the length of `Y` (let's say `len(Y)=4`) and `k` can be either an arbitrary number or `np.max(Y) + 1` (here, `k=3`).

```
import numpy as np

Y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 0])
k = np.max(Y) + 1
n = len(Y)

matrix = np.zeros((k, n))
matrix[Y, np.arange(0, n)] = 1

print(matrix)
```

Output:

```
# When k = np.max(Y) + 1
[[0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]]

# When k = 5 (an arbitrary number)
[[0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```